# Accessing Class Data Members in ViewController.m (xCode / Objective C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a class myClass and would like to access its properties, a `NSArray *currentOptions` (specifically to get the size of `currentOptions` and access the NSStrings which I've put in it.)

I have a method called generate options which assigns an filled array to `*currentOptions`. Generate options is called before I try to access `*currentOptions`. An instance of myClass has also been added to the ViewController via the App delegate. However when buttonOnePressed is called,  I keep getting this error:

> [myClass currentOptions]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b10490

Here is the parts of my code:

```
 //TClass.h
@interface TClass : NSObject {
        NSArray *currentOptions;

    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *currentOptions;
    @end


//viewController
- (IBAction) buttonOnePressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button1 pressed");
    NSLog(@"int: %d",[myClass.currentOptions count]); 
    //myClass here is the instance of TClass
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that sometimes causes that error is failing to properly retain myClass. (Aside: "myClass" is a really bad name for a pointer because the thing being pointed to is almost certainly not a class but an object, i.e. an instance of a class.) If you don't retain the object that myClass points to, it will be deallocated. Sometimes, a different object happens to be created at that some location, and you end up sending a message meant for the original object to the new one, which is a different type and doesn't understand the message.

Comment: So that means @property(retain,nonatomic) is useless once I reassign currentOptions? This is because TClass has a method called generateOptions which assigns currentOptions a new NSArray. In this case how do I access the NSArray that currentOptions is currently assigned to?

Comment: Useless? No, not if you're using the property correctly. I think `myClass` is just a bad pointer, and if that's the case then you have a memory management problem somewhere.

Comment: In viewController.h I have a 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet TutorialClass *myTutorialClass;
Would that be enough to properly retain a class or do you think that the fault might lie somewhere else?

Comment: Look at the object at 0x9b10490 (or whatever address is given when you're debugging). That'll be the address stored in the ivar `myClass`, but the object there is likely not the type that you expect. Also, you seem to be grasping at straws on the memory front: please read [Memory Management Guide](http://tinyurl.com/4lqj2yb).

Comment: Hey Caleb you are right. I went into the debugger and it seems that it really is currentOptions which is problematic. In other objects like my questions NSArray it says 16 objects under summary (which is correct) somehow in currentOptions it says {(int)[$VAR count]} objects. I'll take another look at the code and the memory management guide. :)

Answer (score 0):

To all who have been following, the problem has been resolved by making the following changes:

1) Synthesized current options TClass.m

```
@implementation TClass
@synthesize currentOptions;
@end
```

2) I made currentOptions a NSMutableArray instead of a NSArray. This is because I need to reassign values to current options. Somehow it crashes with NSArray and everything goes smoothly with NSMutable array like such

```
@implementation TutorialClass

    if ([currentOptions count] > 0) {
        [currentOptions removeAllObjects];
    }
    [currentOptions addObject:[options objectAtIndex:0]];
    [currentOptions addObject:[options objectAtIndex:1]];
    [currentOptions addObject:[options objectAtIndex:2]];
    [currentOptions addObject:[options objectAtIndex:3]];
```

3) And of course, I'll also have to do the following in the init method of TClass.m

```
currentOptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Now its time to get some food. Thanks Caleb :D